# code folding all of the function on vim

Tags: vim, code-folding

I want to fold all of the functions on vim. My code is written by C language. How to do this?

PS: Functions in here is not enough! For better consideration, every thing which start by { and end by }.

Comment: Is it not already foldable?

Comment: now . no but the code is huge. I want to fold all of the functions automatically. because the number of structures and functions are a lot.

Comment: @icedwater I changed the question

Comment: @icedwater I removed the second part

Comment: Hmm, odd. I have folding set up - even struct definitions are folded. I think your problem is more setting up folding at all than to get x,y,z folded...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a simple `set foldmethod=syntax` in the `.vimrc` should suffice for most file types. Check that you have a well-defined folding schema in `/usr/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin/c.vim`.